# pointers to __global memory inside a __local struct

Tags: c, macos, opencl

I am confused by the OpenCL compiler's response to pointers to global memory inside a struct stored in local memory. Here is a minimal test case:

```
struct Helper {
    unsigned char bytes[32769];
};

struct Main {
    __global struct Helper *h;
};

void __kernel test(void)
{
    __local struct Main m;
}
```

This fails during clBuildProgram, with the error `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`. However, changing the magic number above from `32769` to a lower number allows the program to compile.

When `clBuildProgram` fails, no output is made available via `clGetProgramBuildInfo(… CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG)`. No errors are reported in the system logs.

32k happens to be the amount of per-compute-unit local memory on my video card (an AMD Radeon HD 6750M). But as you can see, I am storing a *pointer* to this large structure, which will be stored in global memory. I'm not attempting to create the structure itself in local memory. So, why does the size of the pointed-to struct make a difference?

This failure happens on my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.8, and also failed on earlier versions of OS X. However, it compiles successfully on my Linux machine with a NVidia graphics card.

My driver program is [here](http://www.nyloncactus.com/random/test.c). (It's just Apple's demo program with a changed kernel). It compiles on OS X with gcc -o test test.c -framework OpenCL .

Answer (score 0):

On a AMD Hardware 6970, I looked to at the ISA Code generated by your kernel, but its a NOOP, so I dont think kernel ever gets executed since there are no instruction only initalization

View of ISA.

```
; --------  Disassembly --------------------

00 NOP NO_BARRIER 
END_OF_PROGRAM
```

View of IL

```
       ;ARGEND:__OpenCL_test_kernel
        func 1026 ; test                        ; @__OpenCL_test_kernel
        ; BB#0:                                 ; %entry
    ret_dyn
ret
endfunc ; test
```

Comment: Right, that's what I expected to happen -- but on my hardware, that doesn't happen. Instead, the compilation fails with `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`.